# AI warning banner for Latin?

Tags: discussion, status-review, asking-questions

According to the powers that be, we can now [request a banner warning against posting AI answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395881/sites-can-now-request-to-enable-a-banner-to-warn-about-their-policy-on-ai-genera).

Broad consensus from [this Meta question](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/640/why-are-you-banning-chatgpt-answers) is sharply in favor of banning AI answers. There seems to be no doubt about that policy.

But to get a banner, we need to request it. So this is a formal question to start that process.

Pro:

We get a banner explicitly warning against breaking of a rule that some might not realize is against the rules. This might keep away those who would inadvertently break the rules, and make clean up easier for those who claimed they were unaware of the policy.

Cons:

Some might not like the aesthetic of having a banner there.

(Rejoinder: You can dismiss it once and it won't show again.)

It might make the site somewhat less usable for new users. Discussion of this point can be found in the comments to the 'no' vote.

My vote is pro-banner as a necessity for the time being. What saith the community?

Comment: Have we had an issue with AI answers up to this point? I haven't noticed any, but maybe the mod team is cleaning up before I have a chance to see anything. Either way, I think my answer would still be "yes."

Comment: @brianpck You're right that we're quick! In truth, after Chat-GPT was released, we had a huge flurry of AI posts, some of which were in limbo as we navigated the policy. Now, it's been intermittent. I certainly don't see it as a major problem with our site as of right now, but I suspect, as things shake up organization-wide, it might be good to get ahead of the curve while we can.

Comment: Would the banner be shown to everyone and always, or are e.g. more experienced users exempt?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta From the first link: "All users will see this banner when posting an answer with the option to dismiss. Once dismissed, logged-in users will not see this banner again." So it will only bother you once.

Comment: Is the banner a strip of text within the answer field like shown in the screenshot of the experiment SE ran? I don't think a banner like that is very intrusive and doesn't introduce any real friction with writing an answer.

Comment: @Adam There is a picture of it in the first link. We lowly mods aren't privy to more information than what's there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, let's get the banner warning against posting AI answers.

Answer (score 1):

No, let's not get the banner warning against AI answers.

Comment: I voted for this as I don't see the site having major issues dealing with AI-generated answers so far, and I prefer for the site to avoid banners as much as possible. So I think it should not be used unless or until it is necessary.

Comment: @Asteroides That's a fair point. FWIW, I don't think it's supposed to look obtrusive, but I can definitely understand disliking unnecessary tooltips, etc.

Comment: @Asteroides From the initial link, "All users will see this banner when posting an answer with the option to dismiss. Once dismissed, logged-in users will not see this banner again." So if the issue is avoiding banners, it would only bother you a single time. After you dismiss it, it would be gone for good.

Comment: I see! Thanks for the clarification. That is a bit better than it being shown repeatedly to the same users, but I think it still might make the site somewhat less usable for new users